# Was Vibhishana powerful?

Tags: ramayana, weapon, rakshasa, vibhishana, daitya

We all know that Vibhishana was a Brahmin-Daitya/Brahmin-Rakshasa and was an ardent follower of Lord Rama. But I think he didn't kill even a single person in the Rama-Ravana war. So, in my view, he shouldn't be called an asura as he did not have any asura-like qualities.

But does Ramayana talk about Vibhishana being a strong warrior or if he wielded any weapons?

Comment: He should be termed as Asur (or Rakshas), as he had the magical powers (Maya) which his people generally have like he could fly, he was also able to identify other disguised as spies, sent into Ram's army by Ravan. But he did not have those Asur characteristics. However, other Asurs like Prahalad have similar good characteristics, but he still was considered as an asur.

Comment: Your explanation is good, so write the same as an answer to the question not in comments section.

Comment: I am glad that you liked my comment, But the comment only explains why Vibhishana can be termed as an Asur, While your question was, was Vibhishana powerful, That is why it will be better to keep it as a comment only. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Vibhīṣaṇa also killed some rākṣasas during the battle between Lakṣmaṇa and Indrajit. Bow & arrow seems to have been his chief weapon.

> Seeing Lakshmana and Indrajit, fighting with commitment to gain
> victory one over the other, like elephants in rut, that strong and
> valiant Vibhishana, wielding his excellent bow, stood there at the
> battle-front, with an intent to behold their combat.
>
> Standing there thus, **Vibhishana stretched his great bow and released
> excellent sharp pointed arrows on those demons.** Falling in exact spot,
> those arrows, hitting like fire, tore the demons into pieces, as
> thunderbolts would cleave large mountains. Even the foremost of
> demons, the attendants of Vibhishana too, rent asunder those valiant
> demons in battle, with pikes, swords and sharp-edged spears.
>
> Surrounded by those demons, Vibhishana shone like an elephant in the
> midst of proud young tuskers. Vibhishana, who knew the timing, spoke
> to the monkeys, who cherished to destroy the demons, the following
> opportune words duly inspiring them. "O chiefs of monkeys! Here stands
> before you, one [Indrajit] who is the last support of Ravana. He is all that is
> left in his force. Why do you stand idle? At the end of this war, if
> this sinful demon is killed, the remaining army is as good as killed,
> except Ravana."
>
> ([Valmiki Ramayana - Yuddha Kanda in Prose - Sarga 89](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga89/yuddha_89_prose.htm))